# Lower quality images in Next.js "Image" vs. normal "img" tag

Tags: html, css, image, next.js

I'm working with Next.js, and for some reason my images are looking somewhat blurry when I use [Next/Image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image).

Here's what my code looks like:

```
  <img src={url} width={articleWidth} />
  <Image
    className="text-center"
    src={url}
    alt={alt}
    width={width}
    height={height}
  />
```

Here's what the images look like (it might be a bit difficult to tell but the `Next/Image` version is clearly blurrier on my monitor).
[image]

A few other pieces of info I noticed

- The version using the `img` tag had an intrinsic size of `2016 x 1663` and the version using `Next/Image` had an intrinsic size of `750x615`

How do I make `Next/Image` images look just as clear as my regular `img` component

Comment: I can't tell the difference between the two in your posted screenshot.

Comment: Using a `2016 x 1663`-sized image for something so-small on-screen is a waste of bandwidth, memory, and client CPU time. You should be pre-generating _appropriately_ resized images which Next.js is already doing for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Next.js creates versions of your image on run time and serves the apt sized image to render.

If you want to opt out of it:

1. You can selectively use the `unoptimized` prop:

```
 <Image
    className="text-center"
    src={url}
    alt={alt}
    width={width}
    height={height}
unoptimized
  />
```

or,

2. Using the [`unoptimized`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized) option in `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
}
```

When above is set true images will be served as is, without any size change.

Comment: If you are using latest nextjs 13 version then i found it doesn't support optimization for SVG images better go with png and jpg.

Comment: A real svg image (one that isn't just using a png under the hood) should never need optimization. It should (usually) be smaller in file size than a png/jpg, and will scale infinitely without pixelation

Comment: i had use this solution, but instead of solving in my case, the image dissapear as an corrupted image, why that? there is another solution?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the quality of the image in Next.js is set to 75. If you want to change the image quality, you can do so by passing the `quality` prop to the `Image` component. For example, to set the quality to 100, use:

```js
<Image src="your-image-source" quality={100} alt="logo"/>
```

read here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#quality